# Bitbucket Pipeline Not fetching latest docker container from private docker hub registry

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, docker-pull

I am working on a bitbukcet Pipeline where I am fetching a container from a private docker hub registry. Here is my problem

1. If I make registry public, it fetches the latest container that I pushed (The behaviour that I wants)
2. If I make it private and push some changes to docker container and then try to pull it in the bitbucket pipeline again, it always fetch the last commit I fetched (when docker registry was public). Not fetch the changes/commits I made after making the docker registry private

Does anyone knows about this issue in Bitbucket Pipeline? Is it some type of cache issues or anything else. Any help will be highly regarded

I want to know how to fetch latest commit from docker hub in bitbucket pipeline

Comment: Have you provided the yaml with authentication to fetch it?

Comment: yes, I provided the username, password and email in image section as guided by bitbucket official website

Comment: Shared pipeline runners feature a docker image cache that will prevent consecutive pulls. You may need to wait for it to expire or force your pipeline to use a new tag/hash.

Comment: @N1ngu that seems true. But I can't find a way to force the pipeline to use a new hash. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Syntax for pinning a docker image hash would boil down to something like `my.regist.ry/my-namespace/my-image@sha256:sha_digest_here` instead of the usual tag or the default `latest` tag. This works on dockerfiles but I am unaware if it is also accepted in the `image` directive for bitbucket pipelines steps.